# Does Entity Framework Code First support this kind of mapping?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Lets assume I have a class model like so:

```
public class BlogPost
{
     ...

     [Key]
     public Guid Id {get;private set;}
     public virtual ICollection Comments {get;private set;}
}
public class Comment
{    
     [Key]
     public Guid Id {get;private set;}
     public string Text{get;set;}
}
```

Don't read too much into my pseudocode here, but what I want to know if:
Do the comment class *have to* have a Guid BlogPostId or BlogPost parent property?

can I model the comment class as I did above, and still have it mapped to the blogpost through the BlogPost.Comments property.
e.g. by providing some other mapping attributes

I don't want aggregate members to know anything about their AR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are not forced to specify post id (i.e. FK) or reference in comment entity when post have navigation property for comments:

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; private set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

In this case EF will generate FK column in Comments table which will have name `BlogPost_Id` (by default it uses parent entity name with parent entity key property name). Also you don't need to mark key column with `[Key]` attribute if column has name like `id` or `TypeNameId`.

Generated tables will look like:

[image]

If you want to change generate FK name without declaring property on comment entity, you can use fluent mappings (generally I suggest you to use fluent mappings instead of data annotation attributes - that will make your entities cleaner). To provide mappings override `OnModelCreating` method of your data context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPost>()
    .HasMany(bp => bp.Comments)
    .WithRequired()
    .Map(c => c.MapKey("PostId"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: Oohh , nice, didn't think it was smart enough to do this by convention only. thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to name the column for the foreign key w/o adding a property for it? e.g. if I want the foreign key to map to an existing column for legacy reasons?